# displaying two arrays causing repeats angular

Tags: html, angular

I've got a problem displaying an array. I've got two arrays :

- a list of channels
- a list of subscriptions containing channels. It's subscribed by users.

```
channels = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "arte",
    "service": "public"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "tf1",
    "service": "private"
  },
 ];
 
 subscriptions = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "startDate": "2022-03-04T00:00:00",
    "endDate": "2023-03-04T00:00:00",
    "userId": 47,
    "channel": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "arte",
      "service": "public"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "startDate": "2022-03-04T00:00:00",
    "endDate": "2023-03-04T00:00:00",
    "userId": 60,
    "channel": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "arte",
      "service": "public"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "startDate": "2022-03-04T00:00:00",
    "endDate": "2023-03-04T00:00:00",
    "userId": 47,
    "channel": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "tf1",
       "service": "private"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "startDate": "2022-03-04T00:00:00",
    "endDate": "2023-03-04T00:00:00",
    "userId": 79,
    "channel": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "tf1",
      "service": "private"
    },
  },
 ]
```

I've got two parts on my webpage : one where I display the channels subscribed by the user. And the second with the list of channels.

```
<h1>Already subscribed</h1>

<div *ngFor="let sub of subscriptions">
  <div *ngIf="user === sub.userId">
    <div class="card">{{sub.channel.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Our offers</h1>

<div class="display">
<div *ngFor="let chan of channels">
  <div *ngFor="let sub of subscriptions">
     <div *ngIf="sub.userId != user || (sub.channel.name != chan.name && sub.userId === user) || (sub.channel.name === chan.name && sub.userId != user)">
   <div class="card"> {{ chan.name }}</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My problem is : I need to remove the channels from the "our offers" if the user has a subscription for the channel (it's a view by user, the user is connected with a unique ID). My problem is with this line :      `<div *ngIf="sub.userId != user || (sub.channel.name != chan.name && sub.userId === user) || (sub.channel.name === chan.name && sub.userId != user)">` It keeps repeating the channels because of the *ngFor. Do you know how to remove the channels that have already been subscribed by the user ?

Comment: I would suggest filtering the channels in your TypeScript as opposed to using ungainly `*ngIf` conditions in the template.

Comment: can you tell me how this would work ? I've found some documentation and tried it but it's still repeating the values

Comment: I think what you really need is a change of data structure. Eliseo provided one example, but it leads to a lot of iterating over arrays. You could set your subscriptions and channels as dictionaries, and then create indexes of which channels are subscribed and which aren't.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Really I didn't understand the question at all.-I thought that need group the channels by user, and he want show the channels that an user has not subscribe yet :(-

why not create an object like,e.g.?

```
subscriptionsBychannels = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "arte",
    "service": "public",
     subscription:[
          {"id:1",
           "startDate": "2022-03-04T00:00:00",
           "endDate": "2023-03-04T00:00:00",
           "userId": 47}
          },
          {"id": 4,
           "startDate": 2022-03-04T00:00:00,
           "endDate": 2023-03-04T00:00:00,
           "userId": 79}
      ]
  },
  ...
]
```

you can simply

```
group(channels:any[],subscriptions:[])
{
   return channels.map(x=>({
       ...x,
       subscriptions:subscriptions
                      .filter(s=>s.channel.id==x.id)
                      .map(s=>({
                              id:s.id,
                              startDate:new Date(s.startDate),
                              endDate:new Date(s.endDate),
                              userId:s.usrId
                                 }))
      })
}
```

see that you can transform the dates in a javscript object Date

Comment: This is really costly though, that's a helluva lot of array iterations.

Comment: Really I didn't understand the question at all.-I thought that need group the channels by user, and he want show the channels that an user has not subscribe yet :(-

Comment: Fair enough. No matter the requirement, though, this solution is extremely costly. It looks like the best bet for OP is to change data structures.